# Original proof of Lefschetz's theorem on $(1,1)$ classes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, hodge-theory

Is there a "modern" account of Lefschetz proof of his theorem about $(1,1)$ classes for projective surfaces ?

I believe that would be very interesting to understand the original arguments and also a nice applications of pencils of curves. The sketch of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_theorem_on_(1,1)-classes) is quite nice but I would love to see more details about the theorems by Poincaré and Lefschetz mentioned in the Wikipedia sketch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like chapter 6 of

Lewis, James D. *A survey of the Hodge conjecture*,
Second edition, Appendix B by B. Brent Gordon, CRM Monogr. Ser., 10, American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1999.

It has lots of nice pictures too.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for.